# Typescript: infer payload type and pass it to callback

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Here is a simplified example of typing my Redux store.

```
interface SetNamePayload { name: string; }

export interface Action<TPayload extends object> {
    type: string;
    data: TPayload;
}

type SetNameAction = Action<SetNamePayload>;

// derive payload type from action type
type ResolveActionPayload<A extends Action<any>> =
    A extends Action<infer P> ? P : never;

// return type should be resolved to SetNamePayload
function getPayload<T extends SetNameAction>(x: T): ResolveActionPayload<T> 
{
    // TS2322: Type 'SetNamePayload' is not assignable to
    // type 'ResolveActionPayload<T>'.
    return x.data;
}
```

Why is the return type not resolved to `SetNamePayload`, or is it possible to somehow else determine the type of action payload declared like this?

It seems that the generics on `getPayload` are wrong somehow, because the `ResolveActionPayload` works as expected:

[image]

There are of course lot more action types in real code. The function actually looks more like `getPayload<T extends SomeAction | OtherAction | ...>`. This is really an MWE of the problem.

Also, I know that I can reverse the typings and use payload type as the generic parameter, like `getPayload<T>(x: Action<T>): T`, which will probably work much simpler and better. However, this kind of typing is used widely over the code base which is not all mine and it would need a lot of refactoring which I want to try to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the conditional type seems equivalent to the type of the `data` property of the action typescript can't figure this out. Conditional types are generally not expanded if they contain unresolved type parameters. While there are plenty of cases where it would make sense to do so, these cases are pretty specialized and generally not implemented in the compiler.

In this case it would be easier to express the type as a type query. This is easier for the compiler to figure out is the same type as `x.data`. This works

```
function getPayload<T extends SetNameAction>(x: T): SetNameAction['data'] 
{
    return x.data;
}
```

[Playground link](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoTAOTgWwgBTgE8AbAezgBNkBvZEXCALmQGcwpQBzAbmQF8AUIIgAPAA5koYZKEixEKAIIIwwMiAA8AFUKkK1MZBCVWyMgCMAVhFUA+WoOTPkYIuOZsO3Hk5eU4MDgWXWJyKl8hQTcPNAxsPBU1DWQAXmQk9S10LEY9cMo7X0EAehLkSmhgADcUcTCDV3cUGCgyHGREZJAmj2jm5AAlCFYyElrMjXyDTSVkIwgTM0mtOBAiOwdUv2c5haWM1SzNUBhoZHwHAH4L5BYQCFqoYrLkKAwAVygemJRWAAsyB8SNQLCh3qNxhBqGAyHFcnhplRBDAPiAjikuBgkZQdPNRMZTPCEhAVnYABSiEIAShYORJKwA2gByAJBZkAXWQghoOzen2+yFEADo2XBIkA)